# Mappings which Preserve Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find all of the continuous scalar valued functions $f:\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad f(AB) = f(A)f(B)$ for all $A,B$.

This is different than a ring homomorphism because we don't require that $f(A+B)=f(A) + f(B)$, however I do believe that they would work here. Does anyone have any insight? Thank you!

Comment: Can you point out a specific nonconstant function $f$?

Comment: Could you explain what the domain of $f$ is supposed to be? The notation isn't familiar to me.

Comment: Well, what about the determinant function? $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: Also, to Mr. Chip, the domain of f is all linear $n\times n$ matrices on the complex numbers. I apologize if I wrote the notation in the incorrect LaTeX code.

Comment: A more standard notation might be $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{C}(\Bbb{C}^n)$.

Comment: Nick, is it true that all continuous scalar valued functions as described above are endomorphisms? I don't feel like that is true...I feel like we would be missing some.

Comment: The domain consists of endomorphisms of the space $\Bbb{C}^n$ (these are just all $n$-by-$n$ matrices). The maps $f$ in question are not endomorphisms. The word "endomorphism" implies that the domain and range are the same, so of course the $f$'s are not.

Comment: Oh thank you! I haven't studied endomorphisms, so that is good to know. The question I asked came up in my ODE course. I know that if f is the determinant function, then it is true. Maybe it is true for functions on the characteristic polynomial...?